# Running Time Analysis for Iterative sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, analysis

I'm learning how to write theoretical analysis for the running time of algorithms and I am wondering if it's correct to say for the following code:

```
while(high >= low) {
     loop body here....
     high--;
     low++;
}
```

Where low begins at index 0, and high begins at index N - 1, for an array of N integers. The loop body will run `(n / 2) times`, or it will make `(n / 2) + 1` comparisons. Is it correct to say this? And if so, to get the complete run time analysis for the whole function, would you then evaluate any inner loops to create a complete function for the run time?

Comment: Of course the inner functions are needed for a complete analysis of this function. Your outer loop will be in O(n), but if your inner function is non-constant, the complete analysis will be worse than O(n) / (I'm ignoring constants. In your case: i'm ignoring n/2).

Comment: Yah it's O(n) but am I right in my thinking prior to eliminating the constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code section called `loop body here.....` of your code, you may have some other loop running with a complexity of some f(n). The given while loop is going to run *n / 2* times if n is even and *(n / 2) + 1* times if n is odd.

So, the running time complexity of outer loop would be simply **O(n / 2) = O(n)**.

Now,

- if the `loop body here.....` code section is fiddling with `high` and/or `low`, then the complexity of this while loop will vary.
- if the `loop body here.....` code section is O(1) and it doesn't modify `high` and/or `low`, then the overall run-time is O(n).
- if the `loop body here.....` code section is O(n) and it doesn't modify `high` and/or `low`, then the overall run-time is O(n<sup>2</sup>).
- In general, if the `loop body here.....` code section is O(f(n)) and it doesn't modify `high` and/or `low`, then the overall run-time is O(n * f(n)).

Comment: So if high and low are only being used for comparisons and index position, but the values aren't being changed then the  complexity would be O(n^2) correct?

Comment: @cwattsdis: Nope. The complexity will be O(n). See the second bullet.

Comment: But if it was a for loop inside the while loop that runs n - 1 times then it would be O(n^2) right?

Comment: @cwattsdis: Happy to do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91338/discussion-between-cwattsdis-and-displayname).

Comment: @cwattsdis: I just saw your last comment in the chat. Yes it would be (n/2)/2.